# Different top links for different customer groups

Tags: php, magento

I need the "check out" and "my cart" top link hidden to users that aren't logged in and that aren't part of a customer group. I was looking around in the source code but it seems that all the links are pulled from the XML. If anybody knows how I can approach this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should remove checkout and cart links from top links for not-logged-in users:

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <remove name="checkout_cart_link" />
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

I don't know how to do the same for customers that aren't part of a selected customer group.

Comment: You should not edit core files, better add this in your theme's local.xml

Comment: Thanks, added to local.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Although you can show and hide top links via XML if customer is logged in or logged out, i coudnt find a solution to show or hide certain top links based on customer group.

heres what I did

1. copied base/template/page/template/links.phtml into my theme directory
2. made conditional to remove top links if they had 'My Cart' or 'Checkout' and if customer group was id 2 (or whatever id the group is)

heres how my links.phtml file ended up

```html
<?php
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); // var $session  Mage_Customer_Model_Session
$customer = $session->getCustomer(); // var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
$userinfo = $customer->_origData; // fetch users info
// get user's customer group id number
$customer_group = $userinfo['group_id'];
?>
<?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
<?php if(count($_links)>0): ?>
<ul class="links"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>
        <?php if ($_link instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract):?>
            <?php echo $_link->toHtml() ?>
            
        <?php // check to see if customer group id 2 is not in list to show default top links 
  elseif ($customer_group != 2): ?>
            <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
        
        <?php // check to see if my cart or checkout are in links and remove  from top links for customer group id 2
  elseif ($_link->getTitle() != 'My Cart' && $_link->getTitle() != 'Checkout'): ?>
            <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```